# How do I use excel solver to solve this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

ABC Corporation is a Global Distributor of electrical parts and components. The company contracts to
purchase components and parts from Europe, and it has them delivered to warehouses in three
European Ports, E1, E2, E3. The various components and parts are loaded into containers based on
demand from U.S customers. Each port has a limited fixed number of containers available each month.
The containers are then shipped overseas by container ships to the ports of P1, P2, P3, and P4. From
these seaports, the containers are typically coupled with trucks and hauled to inland ports in I1, I2, and
I3. There are a fixed number of freight haulers available at each port each month. These inland ports are
sometimes called “freight villages” or intermodal junctions, where the containers are collected and
transferred from one transport mode to another (i.e. from truck to rail to vice versa). From the inland
ports, the containers are transported to ABC’s distribution centers in D1, D2, D3, D4, and D5. Following
are the handling and the shipping costs ($/container) between each of the embarkation and destination
points along this overseas supply chain and available containers at each port:

[Sample excel sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LGQ-1iCgDew9XUbwCtglwPzEM0f_z40quW5hypkf018/edit?usp=sharing)

A red cell signifies that the particular route is not a viable option and hence, cannot be considered.
Determine the optimal shipments from each point of embarkation to each destination along this
overseas supply chain that will result in minimum total shipping cost and the total shipping cost incurred
at each stage.

Comment: So if something was shipped from P1 to E1 to I1 to D1, the total cost would be $2,769? So you want to find the least expensive route given all these options? Is it a one-time thing or do you want to do something way more complicated like keep track of how many trucks / trains / boats are in use to find the least expensive option at any given time that's actually available?

Comment: @EngineerToast  i want to keep track of the containers and the cost.

Comment: Upon re-reading and based on your comments, my understanding is this: You explicitly want to use the Solver Add-In to figure out the route that each container should take each month to go from Europe to one of several Destinations. Each Destination wants to receive a certain number of containers each month and you want to minimize the total cost of all shipments, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of setting up your problem for Solver. You may be able to make it more compact, but the way I set it up is easy to diagnose any problems.

1. Use your original data in a "Data" tab.
2. Create a new tab, I called "Equation", to set up the Solver problem.
3. Columns A through D are used to set up all of the possible combinations of routes. e.g. Row 1 is headers; Row 2 is E1, P1, I1, D1; Row 2 is E1, P1, I1, D2; etc.
4. Column E through G are the costs associated with Europe to US Port, US Port to Inland port, and Inland port to Distribution center. This is populated using VLOOKUP and MATCH. e.g. in E2 is `=VLOOKUP(A2,Data!$A$3:$E$5,MATCH(B2,Data!$A$2:$E$2,0),FALSE)`; in F2 is `=VLOOKUP(B2,Data!$A$11:$D$14,MATCH(C2,Data!$A$10:$D$10,0),FALSE)`; in G2 is `=VLOOKUP(C2,Data!$A$20:$F$22,MATCH(D2,Data!$A$19:$F$19,0),FALSE)`. These are all filled down.
5. Column H is the total Unit cost. To make non-viable routes obvious, I set the total cost for those to 1,000,000. e.g. H2 is `=IF(OR(E2=0,F2=0,G2=0),1000000,SUM(E2:G2))`. This is filled down.
6. Column I is the number of units (containers) that travel that route. This column is going to be manipulated by solver. I initialized every row with 1.
7. Column J is the total cost for the route. e.g. J2 is `=H2*I2` and is filled down.
8. Another table is built on the same tab to contain the objective function and constraints. It's in L1 through O19. Some examples of the calculations here include: nUnits are sums from the previous table, so the number of containers from E1 is `=SUMIFS($I$2:$I$181,$A$2:$A$181,L2)`, the number of containers from P1 is `=SUMIFS($I$2:$I$181,$B$2:$B$181,L5)`, etc.; maxUnits are extracted from the Data tab, so the maximum containers from E1 is `=VLOOKUP(L2,Data!$A$3:$F$5,6,FALSE)`, the maximum containers from I1 is `=HLOOKUP(L9,Data!$B$10:$D$15,6,FALSE)`, etc.; similarly, demand units are extracted from the Data tab.
9. I added an additional constraint to ensure no non-viable routes are selected.
10. The objective is the total cost, which is the sum of Column J.

Here is a screen capture of the Equation Tab, before running Solver. Several rows are hidden.

[image]

The Solver set up is as follows:

1. Set Objective: is `$M$19`
2. To: is Min
3. By Changing Variable Cells: is `$I$2:$I$181`
4. Make Unconstrained Variables Non-Negative is un-selected (this is handled with constraints)
5. Select a Solving Method: is Evolutionary. Evolutionary is much faster than the other methods when handling integer constraints.
6. Subject to the Constraints: is many ...

   - `$I$2:$I$181 = integer` - must have integer numbers of containers
   - `$I$2:$I$181 >= 0`  - cannot incur negative costs
   - `$M$2 <= $N$2` duplicated for each row to `$M$11 <=$N$11` - do not violate maximum number of containers
   - `$M$12 = $O$12` duplicated for each row to `$M$16 = $O$16` - satisfy demand
   - `$M$17 = $N$17` - do not use non-viable options

Below is a screen shot of the Solver Parameters dialog box ...

[image]

With this setup, I get a total cost of $1,661,119.00 with all demand satisfied and no constraints violated. Below is a screen shot of the constraints table ...

[image]

Below is a screen shot of the cost table, with all zero routes filtered out ...

[image]

Comment: couldn't check this solution. will try this week. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one-time answer, the cheapest route is `E2 > P4 > I2 > D2` at a cost of $1,452.

The method I used was not elegant. I made a table of every possible option, used `INDEX` and `MATCH` to look up the cost of each of leg of the trip, and then sorted by total cost ascending. Here's what my sheet looks like:

[image: Spreadhseet]

The data on the left is what I copied from your spreadsheet. The table on the right is what I created. For each of the fields E, P, I, & D, I just manually typed them in groups. D1, D2, D3, D4, D5. Copy those five and paste them down a lot. I1, copy down for a set of D's, I2, copy down for a set of D's, etc. until the table was filled. For the field $EP, I combined `INDEX` and `MATCH` to lookup the cost of traveling from E(whatever) to P(whatever).

```
=1/(1/INDEX($B$3:$E$5,MATCH([@E],$A$3:$A$5,0),MATCH([@P],$B$2:$E$2,0)))
```

`INDEX` takes in an array and returns a cell from somewhere within that array. To find the row I wanted, I used `MATCH` to find where the E value was in the range `A3:A5`. To find the column, I looked for the P value in `B2:B4`. That gave me the cost of going from E to P. I added the `1/(1/...)` wrapper around the entire thing so it would return an error if the leg of the trip was zero, indicating that it was not available.

I then copied that formula to the fields $PI and $ID, adjusting each to reference the correct ranges. Finally, the Total Cost field simply added those three legs together. I sorted ascending and found the cheapest route. All the errors - the ones using unavailable routes - were sent to the bottom.

---

If you want an ongoing system where you want to keep track of how many transports are current en route for each leg of the trip so you can select the cheapest route based on what's currently available, you may want to look at a database solution. Alternatively, you can use the sorted list and just start at the top, working down until you find a route where each leg is currently available.

Comment: have you taken the number of containers into consideration?

Comment: and any idea to use excel solver in this?

Comment: @DarklordAchilles If you want to have this be a running operation where you can have it tell you which is the cheapest available route right now based on container availability, you might want to look at an actual database so you can track all your shipments en route.

Comment: Even I like a database solution. But this assignment is to learn solver and I can't find how to solve these many levels using it.